не работает focus у элемента input
Много чего перепробовал, у меня такой скрипт:
<script>
const inputs = document.getElementsByName("digit-input")
        
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        const currentInput = event.target
        const index = parseInt(currentInput.id) - 1
        
        if (currentInput.value.length >= currentInput.maxLength) {
            if (index + 1 < inputs.length) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    inputs[index + 1].focus()
                    inputs[index + 1].click()
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
    });
}

setTimeout(() => {
    inputs[0].focus()
    inputs[0].click()
}, 1000)
</script>

и такие элементы:
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-1d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="1">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-2d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="2">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-3d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="3">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-4d-grid-item" name="digit-input" >
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1"id="4">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-5d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="5">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-6d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="6">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-7d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="7">
</div>
<div class="grid-item wrapper diget-wrapper email-ver-8d-grid-item" name="digit-input">
    <input class="input-text input-text-diget text xx-large" maxlength="1" id="8">
</div>

но и при заходе на страницу, и при заполнении input'а - не работает. Есть ли у кого догадки?(

А чего вы хотите на выходе получить, бо у вас тут какойто бредок написан... "вроде как" циклом пройти по всем элементам, добавить каждому фокус, но при этом нажать на инпут и паралельно через секунду фигачить фокус/клик по первому элементу. Как оно вообще должно работать по вашему ?

Первое, что сходу бросается в глаза, так это то, что вы собираете и перебираете элементы div и на него же вешаете слушателя ввода. В то время как реально addEventListener должен слушать input-ы. И это только на поверхности, не говоря о том, что и всё остальное тут — каша и бессмыслица. Если дополните текст смысловой нагрузкой того, что вы хотите сделать на самом деле, то и код можно будет сделать не только рабочим, но и упростить.

@BlackStar1991 я предполагал, что для начала, я добавлю всем инпутам ивент ввода, а после выполнения цикла, сфокусироваться на первом элементе.

@stylok Я хотел при входе на страницу перейти на первый элемент ввода, а после, при вводе в инпут текста, переходить к следующему

Я уже сказал где у вас "неисправность." В текущем представлении кода вам нужен document.querySelectorAll('.input-text') в первой строке, и всё заработает. Но, то как оно работает, выглядит бредово. Отсюда и мой вопрос: "чего вы хотите добиться"? Зачем вам таймер? Чтобы улучшить код, необязательно вешать слушателя на все инпуты, а нужен один на всю форму (обёртку) и т.д. Без понимания того, что и с какой целью вы это наворотили, нет смысла улучшать. Короче, попробуйте мою правку, а потом посмотрите на результат, думаю поймёте о чём я.

@stylok только сейчас дошла истинная ошибка.. Я обращался к дивам, а не к инпутам.. Извините за такой глупый вопрос, я каюсь
